# How to find maximum number of groups of all distinct values from an array of integer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

For example, given an array {2,4,2,4,3,2,3}, 
distinct array is {2,3,4}.
So, 2 such groups are possible for the given array. Another example,
for {1,2,1,3,4,4,3,3},
distinct array is {1,2,3,4} and
only 1 such group can be formed from the given array.

My solution is:

```
    int arr[] = {2,3,4,2,4,3,2};
    Map<Integer, Integer> map  = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int count = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], 0)+1;
        map.put(arr[i], count);
    }
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i : map.values()) {
        if(i < min) {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min);
```

Is there a way to further optimize it ?

Comment: on what do you want to optimize? Size of code? Runtime? Size of executable binary? It is not clear. A general note: With HashMap you are using a quite complex data structure. That is very well, if you go for a short and elegant code. There may be faster solutions with handmade structures, but it also be that such optimizations lead to a dead end. Personally I think your solution is elegant. What is the purpose of this whole question?

Comment: better time or/and space complexity ?

Comment: For asymptotic time complexity, your code is optimal. I wouldn't worry about constant factor time optimizations. You could use streams to make the code prettier, but I wouldn't worry much about that either.  If you want better space complexity without mutating the input array, you'll probably need O(n^2) time.  If you're allowed to sort the input without a copy, then can easily achieve O(n log n) time in constant space.

Comment: Sorting may improve the solution - there would be no implementation complexity, so actual performance (not asymptotic complexity) will be much better. Also you can use count sort approach - the solution will work in O(n) time with O(maxValue) space. However I would suggest you to spend your time on something else, unless you are trying to optimize a piece of code that handles heavy load (in which case your question lacks a lot of details).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript`

```js
let maxValue=Math.max.apply(null,[1,5,6,43,5,6,1,2])
console.log(maxValue)
```

`